# VS Code - Prevent Format Document from putting CSS on one line

Tags: html, css, plugins, formatting, visual-studio-code

I use format document a ton in VSCode and was wondering if there was a way to prevent VSCode from concatenating my CSS classes into one line and leave them as is?

For example, I'd have some CSS like below

```
.a,
.b {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

Then when formatting the document is complete, it'll look like this:

```
.a, .b {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

Is this something that can be prevented with VSCode or is there a plugin that I can install to do the same thing?

Comment: If you look at the built-in css linting options for vscode (https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/CSS#_customizing-css-sass-and-less-settings)  I don't think any of them do such reformatting as that.  Are you sure you don't already have an extension, like prettier or stylelint, that is doing that reformatting?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I went through my plugins and found out that I had a plugin called CSS Formatter installed which was causing this problem. Uninstalling it has fixed the issue, but now I can't beautify my content. Will look into it. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options.

1) You can use the js-beautify plugin (or similar) - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.beautify. Once installed you can use the 'preserve_newlines' setting in the .jsbeautifyrc config file

2) This can be done in vscode settings under the option 'html.format.preserveNewLines'